# Why is my dog's fur growing back so unevenly after shaving?

Tags: dogs, grooming

I have a pharaoh hound. I have had her for about a year now. During spring this year(I think it was in May or maybe early June) she was shaved. My dad shaved her in such a way that it looked like cubism(which is a style of art that is all about squares and cubes).

At first it was growing back normally. But at some point some of the hair on her back dramatically slowed down in growth. To compensate for it there was a dramatic increase in the amount of hair on her back legs.

Why would hair grow normally and then all of a sudden abnormally? Does she have cancer in her hair follicles of her legs and an early telogen phase on a part of her back or something?

Comment: How old? Any other signs like muscle wasting (their head will start to look more "skull"-like, or sunken, thin back legs)? Cushings disease can affect hair growth. Our elderly Golden had it and his hair stopped growing in some places.

Comment: My dog is only 3 years old and no there are no other signs besides dramatic decrease in hair growth on her back and dramatic increase in hair growth on the back legs. The hair that is growing really fast, in the right light it looks like large flakes. I often pick excess hair off those areas to minimize the flakiness. I do make sure that when I do that, I am not hurting my dog.